# adding a div block to all pages except a particular page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add this div block to my application.html.erb so that it will show in all pages. So I done like below.

```
<div class="contaner-fluid custom-padding full-page-height">

</div>
```

But I dont want to show it on my `home` action.So is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the above code to this

```
<% unless params[:action] == 'home' %>
    <div class="contaner-fluid custom-padding full-page-height">

    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters) says:

> The params hash will always contain the :controller and :action keys,
>   but you should use the methods `controller_name` and `action_name` instead
>   to access these values

Definitely, you may make use of `controller_name` and `action_name` to check if it's the one that you wish to exclude. Assuming your controller name is `foos` then you can do the following:

```
<% if !(controller_name == "foos" && action_name == "home") %>
<div class="contaner-fluid custom-padding full-page-height">

</div>
<% end %>
```